# git status: How to ignore content changes?

Tags: git

I'm not interested in file content changes, just:

- if new file is created
- file is removed
- file is renamed (combination of the first 2 items)

So if file already committed is temporarily changed it should not be listed, because the filename was not changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
git status --porcelain | grep -v '^ M '
```

or

```
git status | grep -Pv '^\tmodified:' | grep -P '^\t'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).